# Put a list of matched values into a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have a small excel worksheet such as:

```
        A               B               C
1                       Best Choices->  Aspen, Oak, Maple
2
3       Wood Type       Score
4       Aspen           8.5  
5       Oak             8.6  
6       Elm             7.1
7       Hickory         7.5  
8       Maple           8.2
```

I need to check the values in Column B and if the Score is equal to or greater than 8 (for example), list the matching values from Column A into a single cell in C1 as shown.  I've tried numerous Index, Match, Vlookup examples but have not been able to make this work.

I would think the formula would be pretty simple but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First enter the following UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function ListUm(rng As Range, crit As Double) As String
    Dim rw As Long, L As Long
    rw = rng.Rows.Count
    For L = 1 To rw
        If rng(L, 2) >= crit Then
            ListUm = ListUm & ", " & rng(L, 1)
        End If
    Next
    ListUm = Mid(ListUm, 3)
End Function
```

Then in C1 enter:

**=ListUm(A4:B8,8)**

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly.  No way to do this with just an excel formula then correct?  Just curious.  Thanks again.

Comment: I tried the formula thing first, using concatenated VLOOKUP()s.  Gave up because there are an unknown number of matches.....forced to use VBA..........maybe a smarter formula person will add an Answer to this post...........

Comment: One other question... Column B has formulas from row 4 to 100 but may only contain data in the first 50 rows.  When the results are put into the cell (C1), they are listed as Item1, Item2, Item3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,. I have tried to change the rng.rows.count to something like rng("A4", rng("A4").End(xlDown)).Count but I end up with the same result.  (Column A does not have formulas so I was trying to count the number of rows from A4 to end.down).  The row count is still counting all the rows, even those without data but contain formulas.  Can you show me the correct syntax?

Comment: I don't understand......can't you control this in the worksheet??......... **=ListUm(A4:B8,8)** covers 5 rows......... **=ListUm(A4:B13,8)** would cover 10 rows....etc...

Comment: Right, that works fine. The sheet will be sent to several folks who can add more entries and scores so I'm prepping the sheet to calculate those additional entries.  If and until the empty rows have data in them, the resulting 'top scorers' list gets padded with the extra commas.